# Homestead multiple sites not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I'm a newbie on laravel, and running homestead I had one site before added another one did not work. I destroyed homestead and started once again and added two sites in Sites section in homestead.yaml file the bluprint of my homestead.yaml file is below

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel

sites:
    - map: project1.dev 
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel/project1/public

    - map: project2.dev 
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel/project2/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I added those two sites in my `/etc/hosts` file as well blueprint is below

```
#laravel maps
192.168.10.10 project1.dev
192.168.10.10 project2.dev
```

but when i run project1.dev or project2.dev they both show me the content of project1.dev files

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I needed to the `vagrant provision` command to restart the server and register the changes that I have made

so once you finished with `homestead.yaml` and `/etc/hosts` file run this

```
vagrant provision
```

Comment: What else did you have to do? I'm having the same problem, even if i provision with the mentioned command: 'vagrant provision' @Amjad

Comment: what is the issue @tblancog, running `vagrant provision` resolved all my issues at that time.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use tabs on the file, use only spaces to indentation and this will solve the problem.

Now, only run

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

To reload the configuration file.

Note: If you use vagrant destroy and vagrant up, you lose everything on your VM.

Answer (score 1):

Like how [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#per-project-installation) says, you can install Homestead directly into your project, require it using this `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` at root directory of each project you have. Now by `make` command you can generate `Vagrantfile` and `Homestead.yaml` file into your project's root directory.

- Mac/Linux:

  ```
  php vendor/bin/homestead make
  ```
- Windows:

  ```
  vendor\bin\homestead make
  ```

On each project root you will have a `Homestead.yaml` file to edit:

- Project-A

  ```
  ip: "192.168.10.10"
  ...
  folders:
      - map: "~/Code/projecta"
        to: "/home/vagrant/projecta"
  sites:
      - map: project.a
        to: "/home/vagrant/projecta/public"
  ```
- Project-B

  ```
  ip: "192.168.10.11"
  ...
  folders:
      - map: "~/Code/projectb"
        to: "/home/vagrant/projectb"
  sites:
      - map: project.b
        to: "/home/vagrant/projectb/public"
  ```

Add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
    192.168.10.10 project.a
    192.168.10.11 project.b
```

Then you have to cd to each project's root and `vagrant up`.
Now if you `vagrant ssh` from each project, you will have that project in your VM environment.

Of course there is a `Homestead.yaml` file inside `~/.homestead`, but vagrant goes for the `.yaml` file that is located inside project root first. In my case, the `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` file is ignored.

Comment: why would you create a new vm for every project?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems trying to provision when I had more than 50 or so sites running under apache - the process aborted at a certain point due to how long it took after each one was added for apache to restart.

My workaround was to do the following:

1. Make a copy of homestead.yaml
2. Temporarily remove all the sites in the homestead.yaml file BEFORE the one where the failure occurred.
3. Create a new folder as root at /etc/apache2/sites-parked and move all the links in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled into it:

```
    sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/sites-parked;
    sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/* /etc/apache2/sites-parked/;
    exit;
```

4. Reprovision vagrant again to bring in all the new sites with their SSL certs
5. Assuming that things worked this time and the provision process completed, go back and move the site linkages you parked earlier back into the right place:

```
    sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-parked/* /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/;
    sudo apache2ctl restart;
```

6. Restore your original fully configured homestead.yaml so you have those settings next time you need them.

I hope this helps someone.